# Pentaho: Connection to SQL-Server failed from Batch though works from Spoon

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I have an issue running PDI job in batch though it's running perfectly from Spoon.

The error is:

> Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)
>   The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "RSA premaster secret error".

Obviously - I've added sqljdbc4.jar to libext\JDBC folder.

Please advise.

Comment: Did you call getCause() on the thrown SQLServerException to get the reason?

Comment: @CPMunich, where I can call getCause()? I'm using Pentaho Kitchen.bat to run the kjb-file job, i.e. I use jar-files, no code. And the same job is running fine from GUI (Spoon.bat).

Comment: can you please specify how you are executing this job.

Comment: The issue has been resolved!
I've applied a fix explained in the following link:
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-4010
and it worked.